How to test and to what extend should I write unit tests?
I am new to unit testing, and currently working on a new release of one of my packages to be testable.
Currently, I am struggling to see when and what to test. Take the following script for reference:
class AuthService {
  AuthService({
    required this.client,
  });

  final SimpleGraphQl client;

  Future<LoginResponseDto> login({
    required String username,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    const query = r'''
      query Login($username: String, $password, String) { 
        login(username: $username, password: $password) {
          success
          token
        }
      }''';

    final variables = {'username': username, 'password': password};

    final response = await client.query<LoginResponseDto>(
        variables: variables,
        query: query,
        resultBuilder: (data) {
          return LoginResponseDto.fromJson(
            data['login'] as Map<String, dynamic>,
          );
        });

    return response;
  }
}

class LoginResponseDto {
  LoginResponseDto({
    required this.success,
    required this.token,
  });

  final bool success;
  final String? token;

  factory LoginResponseDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseDto(
      success: json['success'] as bool,
      token: json['token'] as String?,
    );
  }
}

This service handles authentication logic using a GraphQL wrapper called SimpleGraphQl, which takes the GraphQL query, variables, and a callback for response serialization. The service examples include just the login method.
When deciding which case scenarios I should test, I decided to test:

Client query variables parameter must include username and password keys.
Test success and failure login attempts (e.g. when success in response is either true or false).

So, I wrote the following tests:
void main() {
  group('AuthService', () {
    late SimpleGraphQlMock client;

    setUp(() {
      client = SimpleGraphQlMock();
    });

    test('login mutation includes "username" and "password" variables',
        () async {
      final service = AuthService(client: client);

      when(
        () => client.query<LoginResponseDto>(
          query: any(named: 'query'),
          variables: any(named: 'variables'),
          resultBuilder: any(named: 'resultBuilder'),
        ),
      ).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => LoginResponseDto.fromJson(
          {'success': true, 'token': 'test_eyJhb....sw5c'},
        ),
      );

      await service.login(username: 'john_doe', password: '12345');

      final captured = verify(
        () => client.query<LoginResponseDto>(
          query: any(named: 'query'),
          variables: captureAny(named: 'variables'),
          resultBuilder: any(named: 'resultBuilder'),
        ),
      ).captured;

      /// Login mutation includes username and password variables.
      expect(captured[0].containsKey('username'), true);
      expect(captured[0].containsKey('password'), true);
    });

    test('should login successfully using correct credentials', () async {
      final service = AuthService(client: client);

      when(
        () => client.query<LoginResponseDto>(
          query: any(named: 'query'),
          variables: any(named: 'variables'),
          resultBuilder: any(named: 'resultBuilder'),
        ),
      ).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => LoginResponseDto.fromJson(
          {'success': true, 'token': 'test_eyJhb....sw5c'},
        ),
      );

      final response = await service.login(
        username: 'john_doe',
        password: '12345',
      );

      expect(response.success, true);
      expect(response.token, 'test_eyJhb....sw5c');
    });

    test('login should fail when incorrect credentials are sent', () async {
      final service = AuthService(client: client);

      when(
        () => client.query<LoginResponseDto>(
          query: any(named: 'query'),
          variables: any(named: 'variables'),
          resultBuilder: any(named: 'resultBuilder'),
        ),
      ).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => LoginResponseDto.fromJson(
          {'success': false, 'token': null},
        ),
      );

      final response = await service.login(
        username: 'john_doe',
        password: 'wrong password',
      );

      expect(response.success, false);
      expect(response.token, null);
    });
  });
}


Note: I'm using the mocktail library.

However, my concern is that I don't see value in the second scenario about testing successful and failed login attempts because I'm just forcing a returned object rather than testing code logic. For example, testing that calling this query resolves in the correct JSON response (which, as far as I know, is the responsibility of the package and not my app).
I did not test the type of the login response because I didn't see value in it. If this was a dynamically typed language like TypeScript, I would want to ensure the correct fields are returned. Still, Dart's type system makes it irrelevant. Is that test indeed relevant, or should I take another approach?
In conclusion, I would like to know if the test scenarios I posed are relevant and sufficient and if the test code is correct according to the login use case.

I agree with those tests.
I think it is enough.
